# How to enable HTTP/2 in Spark embedded webserver

Tags: spark-java

How to enable HTTP/2 in embedded Jetty server? It's disabled by default. Spark documentation doesn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look supported out of the box by the current stable version. A 2-year-old [pull request](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/514) exists to add support for HTTP/2, but no idea if it is still applicable.